# How to manipulate DOM element when a factory is updated

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to update a directive:

```
<video class="me" ng-if="User.CurrentRoom.Users[0].isPlaying" ng-src="{{User.CurrentRoom.Users[0].videoSrc}}" autoplay></video>
<video class="other" ng-if="User.CurrentRoom.Users[1].isPlaying" ng-src="{{User.CurrentRoom.Users[1].videoSrc}}" autoplay></video>
```

I would like to call the `pause` méthod of the video element when the user's attribute `isPlaying`` becomes false.

I tried to watch it this way:

```
function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(User.CurrentRoom, function(Room) {
        console.log('CATCH THE EVENT');
    })
}
```

but it's not fired.

Here is the factory:

```
angular.module('myapp').factory('User', function() {
  return {
    Rooms: [],
    CurrentRoom: {}
  }
});
```

How would you do that ? Manipulate a DOM element inside of a directive when a factory changes.

Comment: can you post your factory code?

Answer (score 0):

To deep watch objects, your `$watch` call should set the 3d argument as true. Keep in mind as per the docs:

> When objectEquality == true, inequality of the watchExpression is determined according to the angular.equals function. To save the value of the object for later comparison, the angular.copy function is used. This therefore means that watching complex objects will have adverse memory and performance implications.

```
scope.$watch('User.CurrentRoom', function(Room) {
    console.log('CATCH THE EVENT');
}, true);
```